# Bitbucket webhook not sending payload

Tags: php, git, bitbucket, webhooks

I'm new to webhooks and trying to do automated deployment to my website whenever I push to my repo.

I set up the webhook on my bitbucket repo to a URL which contains a simple php script:

```
if(isset($_POST['payload'])) {
    logMsg("Got stuff\n");
} else {
    logMsg("No stuff\n");
}
```

After I push to my repo, the webhook will request the script fine but no payload is sent. My log file will always say "No stuff".

What am I missing?

Comment: you do know bitbucket has been off/on the past 4 days for errors and attacks

Comment: :o Not really. You think that is the case?

Comment: It isn't the case here.

If you go to the webhooks page on the repo settings, does it report any network error or HTTP error code?

Comment: Nope, no errors. 200 everytime.

Answer (score 5):

The new Bitbucket webhooks send the payload in the request **body**, not in the request headers as the previous "Services" did.
So to access the payload you must read the request body like this :

```
$payload = file_get_contents('php://input');
```

or like that:

```
$payload = stream_get_contents(STDIN);
```

Et voilà !

Answer (score 0):

BitBucket webhook [changed recently (June 2015)](https://blog.bitbucket.org/2015/06/24/the-new-bitbucket-webhooks/).

The new [event payload doc](https://confluence.atlassian.com/bitbucket/event-payloads-740262817.html) refers to a [tutorial page](https://confluence.atlassian.com/bitbucket/tutorial-create-and-trigger-a-webhook-747606432.html) whose example does not test for payload.
See [`atlassianlabs/webhook-listener`](https://bitbucket.org/atlassianlabs/webhook-listener) and its [`listener.py`](https://bitbucket.org/atlassianlabs/webhook-listener/src/793c4c9c9bd5c9cdaafadcfa53fad4693a93f1d8/listener.py?at=master&fileviewer=file-view-default) (python, but the idea would be the same for php)

```
@app.route('/webhook', methods=['GET', 'POST'])
def tracking():  
    if request.method == 'POST':
        data = request.get_json()
```

It tries directly to decode json. If that json data were to be empty,... that would mean no payload.